# Conditional probability with Gamma distribution.

Tags: probability, gamma-function, conditional-probability, gamma-distribution

I am stuck on a vital step in this process, and that is about the conditional probability aspect of it. Once I get that step, the integration and using the gamma function should go fine.

So my question is the following:
Will P[x > 4 | x > 2] = P[x > 4 and x > 2]/P[x>2] = P[x>4] / P[x>2]
OR will it be P[2< x<4]/P[x>2]? The first result gives me a really small probabiliy of **0.0557** and the latter one gives me **0.94**, which are two entirely different answers. Thanks in advance.

[Gamma function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugnwm.png)

Answer (score 1):

By definition of conditional probability, $P(A|B) = P(A \ \text{and}\ B)/P(B)$.

Comment: Right. So will it be that x has to be great than 4 because that is the only intersection between those two?

Comment: "$x > 4$ and $x > 2$" is equivalent to $x > 4$.